# Spring Boot - How to kill current Spring Security session?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

Currently I know that my setup is working because I was able to login properly using the basic HTTP authentication.

I used these properties:

```
security.basic.enabled=true
security.user.name=user
security.user.password=1qaz2wsx
security.user.role=USER
```

However, I want to relogin again. I tried clearing cookies (I assumed it was saved there), I checked my local/session storage and cookies in Chrome dev tools but it was blank.

I tried accessing my site in incognito and it asks me to login (for the first time since I only logged in to Chrome non-incognito).

How do I "kill" my session in Spring Security?

Comment: That is not how basic authentication works. The username/password is send with each request, so clearing sessions, cookies etc. will not work. The only thing that would work is the quit the browser and open en new instance after that. And with quit I mean really quit all the browser windows/tabs/etc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use basic authentication, the browser stores the authentication until you close it (or exit the incognito mode, if you used it). There is no possibility to delete the session on server side, since the browser would just reauthenticate. If you want to be able to logout, use form login.

Comment: Thank you very much! This cleared things up. Actually I am not trying to kill it server-side but I just thought it was saved as a cookie or something! Much appreciated.